# Replacing all null values in attribute table by "no"

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am new to QGIS. This question about how to use the field calculator, because the procedure to replace all fields is explained very nicely in [Replacing all null values from attribute table with zeros using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79627/replacing-all-null-values-from-attribute-table-with-zeros-using-qgis)

I have the null features selected, but now I am struggling to find a means to change all of them to "no" instead of the "0".

Can someone help?

Comment: do you have a text field or a numeric field ?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I find out?

Comment: QGIS 3 : right click on layer > properties > identify icon (i in blue circle), then scroll to fields and you will see the type of field.

Comment: okay, it is string, yes.

Comment: have you tried with 'no' in the field calculator ?

Comment: Null is a missing value, it is also possible you have the text "Null" in your field. So do you want to replace Null (missing value) or the text "Null"?

Comment: I have tried the procedure as suggested by Erik, but it doesn't work. The field looks blank, and when I click on it a grey "NULL" appears, so I think it is the missing value Null

Answer (score 7):

Update your column using the following "code" in the field calculator

`CASE WHEN "field" IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE "field" END`

This doesn't even need you to select all `NULL`-values beforehand - and requires your column to not to be of any numerical data type.

Comment: Alternative: `if( "field" IS NULL, 'no', "field")`. Yours is of course more descriptive. :)

Comment: Thanks Erik and Stefan, and for the "field" I should put the name of my variable without the quotations, yes?

Comment: I usually use CASE WHEN because I find it easier to nest.

Comment: "field" is you columns name - and you have to use the quotation marks. Column names are always refered to by double quotation marks, values (especially strings) by single quotation marks.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. For me the code doesn't work. I put it in the field calculator, replaced the column name, and checked the "update existing field option" but when I click on "ok" nothing happens. Do you have an idea what is happening?

Comment: What data does this column contain?

Comment: It is string and it contains many 'Null' and a couple 'yes'

Comment: Are the 'Null' values grey, or rather black and distinct?

Comment: They are white and only appear when I click on the field.

Comment: Does the preview provided by the field calculator at the bottom left corner of the window when you entered the code look okay?

Comment: The preview field calculator doesn't give problems. It says "Output preview: 'no'". I wanted to send you some screenshots via message but I didn't find how to send you a private message. Is this possible?

Comment: Just add the screenshots via an external uploadservice to your post. This way everybody else can help, too.

Comment: doing this using the QGIS db manager causes it to crash